# How to save VS Code settings and snippets files in another location

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default the user settings for VS Code are saved in `c:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`. Is there a way to change that to save in a custom location? I'd like to save them in my OneDrive folder so my settings and snippets will roam.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answering the question of whether it is possible to change the path of the user settings (which is not possible as far as I know) but there is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) which does the synchronization of settings and snippets.
Maybe this is an option for you.

Comment: Very helpful. I believe it would be simpler if the path could be customized to land in a persons cloud storage path, but this is not a bad second place. Thank you.